# SQL passing values from nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question regarding the proper way to pass values in nested queries for Oracle SQL.  I have the following code:

```
SELECT b.business_id
  FROM business b,
       business_category c,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS catcount
           FROM business_category b1
          GROUP BY b1.list_of_subcategories)    
WHERE b.business_category = c.busn_catg_id
  AND catcount = 1;
```

Where the goal is to look into a table called BUSINESS_CATEGORY and count the number of occurrences there are for all the subcategories.  The query is supposed to return the business ID associated with the businesses whose business subcategory only has a count of 1.  Essentially I want to return the businesses who have a unique subcategory(meaning their subcategory isn't used more than once).

My attempts of doing that can be observed above.  I decided to have a nested query where the inner query returns the count for each of the subcategories and calls its return value Catcount.  I then made sure that the Business_Catg_Id matched up with the Business_Category id's to return the business id's that had the unique categories.

Thus far its not returning what it should and I don't know why at this point.  I was hoping someone could explain why this is the case.  Here are the tables that correspond with this problem:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you are looking for. It should get you a BUSINESS_ID from the BUSINESS_CATEGORY table along with the COUNT of it's sub-categories where this count is equal to 1.

```
SELECT B.Business_Id
      ,COUNT(C.List_Of_Subcategories) AS CatCount
  FROM BUSINESS B
 INNER 
  JOIN BUSINESS_CATEGORY C
    ON B.Business_Category = C.Busn_Catg_Id 
 GROUP
    BY B.BusinessId
HAVING COUNT(C.List_Of_Subcategories) = 1
;
```

Also changed the joins to be ANSI-compliant

**UPDATE**: Added below query to get only those BUSINESS_IDs which have BUSINESS_CATEGORIES and these categories have only a count of 1 sub-category across the them.

```
SELECT B.Busines_ID
      ,B1.CatCount
  FROM BUSINESS B
 INNER
  JOIN (
         SELECT C.Busn_Catg_Id
               ,COUNT(C.List_Of_Subcategories) AS CatCount
           FROM BUSINESS_CATEGORY C
          GROUP
             BY C.Busn_Catg_Id
         HAVING COUNT(C.List_Of_Subcategories) = 1
       ) B1
    ON B.Business_Category = B1.Busn_Catg_Id
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @Gordon - Unsure why you say that, I think the join is pretty much the same you have in your query..

Comment: @vmachan I have a quick question.  For this solution you use B1.List_Of_Subcategories.  Should I add BUSINESS_CATEGORIES B1 to the FROM section next to the BUSINESS B?  Otherwise it won't run correctly because it's missing the B1

Comment: @John123 - Sorry, that was a typo, I fixed the answer now.. this should  work

Comment: @vmachan I think you are referring to the wrong table.  The BUSINESS table doesn't have a List_Of_Subcategories column.  The BUSINESS_CATEGORY table has that column.

Comment: @vmachan I know technically speaking it should return all the businesses who don't have BCT4 and BCT6 Since those both have the same subcategory.  Right now, yours is outputting the individual counts of each occurence of the business right?

Comment: @John123 - Right now, it is returning to you all BUSINESS_IDs that have a COUNT of 1 subcategory, even if these multiple business ids have the same sub-category. You question did not indicate that you need to exclude such records.. if so, then this answer would not help with that..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can calculate `CatCount` using analytic functions.  Then you can just use the value in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT B.Business_Id
FROM BUSINESS B JOIN
     (SELECT C.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY List_Of_Subcategories) as CatCount
      FROM BUSINESS_CATEGORY C
     ) C
     ON B.Business_Category = C.Busn_Catg_Id
WHERE CatCount = 1;
```

I would strongly advise you to learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.